# Special access to enclosing object?

Tags: php, design-patterns, oop

Is there a way, in PHP5.3, for an object $enclosed to know which object $enclosing that it is inside of? Essentially I want to make some variables of $enclosing be accessible only to $enclosed without specifically passing those vars in.

```
class Enclosing {
  private $enclosed;//Enclosed object
  private $othervar;

  function __construct($a,$b){
     $this->othervar=$a;
     $this->enclosed= new Enclosed($b);
  }

}

class Enclosed {
  private $myvar;

  function __construct($a){
    $this->myvar=$a;
  }

  function where_am_i() {//get reference to Enclosing object
    //????
  }
}
```

### Background:

I am working on a Calendar that can display multiple Schedules which have multiple, possibly recurring Events. I am using PHPs DateTime, DateInterval and DatePeriod objects for date handling (they make dealing with timezones and recurrence easier despite their other drawbacks). Currently my design goes like this:

A Calendar object has a DatePeriod called $window which contains all the display dates. e.g. the month of May, 1957.

The Calendar also has an array $schedules of Schedule objects. Each member of $schedules must be aware of $window.  So I implemented the Observer pattern between Calendar and Schedule.

Similarly each Schedule has an array $events of Events, which because they may be recurring, must also be aware of $window. So I implemented the Observer pattern between Schedule and Event.

All of this means that I have a cascade of copying the $window to multiple other objects every time it changes.

It would be much more efficient if the Events in $events knew who their enclosing Schedule was and that Schedule knew who its enclosing Calendar was.  Then when these objects needed to use $window they could just ask for it.

Any thoughts on a good way of making this happen? Is there a pattern I can refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is theoretically impossible. The object is not "enclosed" in anything at all; in an instance of the `Enclosing` class, you merely enclose a *reference* to that object. There could be many references all over the place to the same `Enclosed` instance.

You might be able to declare `Enclosed` inside the `Enclosing` class, but I'm not sure if PHP supports inner classes.

Otherwise, just pass a reference to the `Enclosing` object when creating the `Enclosed` object, and store that in a field of the `Enclosed` object.

Comment: I had a feeling I was looking for magic. But I thought perhaps my $enclosed could examine (via Reflection?) all the instances of $enclosing and find the one that contained itself.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to directly access an object that 'encloses' another object. You either need to pass a reference to the enclosed object, or keep the data in a variable in the enclosed object.